# jQuery address plugin, pathname change when using AJAX

Tags: ajax, wordpress, jquery-address, pathname

I have a Wordpress blog at http://themes.visualise.ca/visualise and when a user clicks on a thumbnail the post is loaded with AJAX (using the jQuery address plugin) . I would like the URL to change at the same time to i.e. for the second thumbnail the url should change to http://themes.visualise.ca/visualise/portfolio/samuel but with the following code it changes to http://themes.visualise.ca/visualise/visualise/portfolio/samuel.

1) So my question is there a way to make the jQuery address replace the current pathname by the destination url's pathname instead of simply adding it at the end? I would like the solution to work also with http://themes.visualise.ca/ to http://themes.visualise.ca/visualise/portfolio/samuel because the blog might not be hosting in a folder like it is right now.

2) Or maybe there is another way to achieve this?

Here is the jQuery code:

```
$('.ajaxed,li.menu-item-object-page a').live('click', function(event) {
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    var rewritepath = $(this)[0].pathname;
    $("html,body").animate({scrollTop: 0}, 300);
    $('#content,.plus').stop().fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $('#board-wrapper').slideDown('slow');
        $('#board').fadeOut('slow', function(){
            $('#board').stop().load(link, function(){
                $('#board').delay(1000).fadeIn('slow', function(){
                    var board_h2 = $('#board').height();
                    $('#board-wrapper').css('height', board_h2 + 'px');
                });
            });
        });
    });
    $.address.crawlable(true).path(rewritepath);
    return false;
});
```

Many thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did is that I removed the root site url from link url and it works.

```
$('.ajaxed,li.menu-item-object-page a').live('click', function(event) {
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    var toRemove = MySettings.url;
    var url_pathname = MySettings.url[0].pathname;
    var rewritepath = link.replace(toRemove,'');
    ...
});
```